# How to reset radio button in react JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to reset the radio button, after adding some form data, but it's not happening in react.

In the add method, I am trying to set the state value of the radio button to blank.

I tried different ways to make the radio button again blank. None of them is working

I see some react js radio button logic.

```
export default class AddColumns extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newItemInput: "",
      selectedDataValue: "",
      buyItems: ["Development", "Testing"],
    };
  }

  handleChangeData = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      selectedDataValue: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  change(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    console.log("button clicked", this.state);
  }

  addColumnItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItemInput = this.state.newItemInput;
    var newRadioDataValue = this.state.selectedDataValue;

    //doing adding stuff, then resetting all fields

    this.setState({
      newItemInput: "",
      newRadioDataValue: "", //but this radio button is not resetting
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form
          id="Form"
          className="form-horizontal"
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            this.addColumnItem(e);
          }}
        >
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="newItemInput">
              Add New Item
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={(input) => (this.newColumn = input)}
              name="newItemInput"
              placeholder="Modules"
              value={this.state.newItemInput}
              className="form-control"
              id="newItemInput"
              onChange={(event) => this.change(event)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label col-sm-3">Data Type:</label>
            <div className="col-sm-5">
              <label className="radio-inline pull-left">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="radioData"
                  value="InputData"
                  onChange={this.handleChangeData}
                />
                Input Data
              </label>
              <label className="radio-inline pull-left">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="radioData"
                  value="TargetData"
                  onChange={this.handleChangeData}
                />
                Target Data
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Add
            </button>
            <p>{this.state.message}</p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same key in your `setState`: `this.setState({ selectedDataValue: '' })`.

Also you only need to specify the changed keys in `setState`:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state, // this line can be removed
  selectedDataValue: event.target.value
});
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to clear the radio selection, you can add in the `checked` prop:

```
state = { ..., radioChecked: false };
...
<input
  type="radio"
  checked={this.state.radioChecked}
  onClick={() => this.setState({ radioChecked: true })}
/>
...
this.setState({ radioChecked: false }); // to clear it
```

Comment: i have defined like below in the add method.
var newRadioDataValue = this.state.selectedDataValue;

Comment: Your object is `{ newRadioDataValue: ''  }` and my object is `{ selectedDataValue: '' }`. These are the keys of the object, your variable is not even being used.

Comment: this.setState({
    newItemInput : '',
    selectedDataValue : '',
  })

Comment: `value="TargetData"` are you trying to change this? It should be `value={this.state.selectedDataValue}`.

Comment: If i will do like that then how can i get the value of the radio button. Thats why for getting the value i am doing "selectedRequiredValue: event.target.value"

Comment: Does your code even work for that currently? Shouldn't the `name` prop be `selectedDataValue`?

Comment: Yes code is working that way and i am getting values of the radio button properly

I did the way you told and its working fine whenever i am adding i am resetting the values of that radio button, but the selection is not going from the UI, means the selection is still there but value is blank.

How to remove that selection also.

Comment: No clue what you mean. Show a screenshot?

Comment: suppose first time i selected "Input" radio button. When i am resetting the radio button, the value changed to "blank" or "empty", but still that selection for "input" radio button is there.

Comment: Updated code to show how you can control the radio `checked` value.